# Cannot replace last element in string List

Tags: c#, list

I have an input file that includes data on an entertainer and their performance score. For example,

```
1. Bill Monohan from North Town 10.54
2. Mary Greenberg from Ohio 3.87
3. Sean Hollen from Markell 7.22
```

I want to be able to take the last number from a line (their score), perform some math on it, and then replace the old score with the new score.
Here's a brief piece of code for what I'm trying to do:

```
string line;
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"file.txt");

//Read each line and split by spaces into a List.
while ((line = reader.ReadLine())!= null){

//Find last item in List and convert to a Double in order to perform calculations.
   List<string> l = new List<string>();
   l = line.Split(null).ToList();
   string lastItem = line.Split(null).Last();
   Double newItem = Convert.ToDouble(lastItem);

   /*Do some math*/
   /*Replace lastItem with newItem*/
   System.Console.WriteLine(line); }
```

When I write the new line, nothing changes but I want lastItem to be switched with newItem at the end of the line now. I've tried using:

```
l[l.Length - 1] = newItem.ToString();
```

But I'm getting no luck. I just need the best way to replace the last value of a string List like this. I've been going at this for a few hours now and I'm almost at the end of my rope.
Please help me c# masters!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expression [MatchEvaluator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c.aspx) to get number from each line, do calculations, and replace original number with new one:

```
string line = "1. Bill Monohan from North Town 10.54";
line = Regex.Replace(line, @"(\d+\.?\d*)$", m => {
            decimal value = Decimal.Parse(m.Groups[1].Value);
            value = value * 2; // calculation
            return value.ToString();
        });
```

This regex captures decimal number at the end of input string. Output:

```
1. Bill Monohan from North Town 21.08
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not changing anything to your line object before doing your WriteLine.

You will have to rebuild your line, something like this:

```
var items = string.Split();
items.Last() = "10";//Replace
var line = string.Join(" ", items)
```

Tip: strings are immutable, look it up.

Comment: This will not compile

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
//var l = new List<string>(); // you don't need this
var l = line.Split(null).ToList();
var lastItem = l.Last(); // line.Split(null).Last(); don't split twice
var newItem = Convert.ToDouble(lastItem, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
/*Do some math*/
/*Replace lastItem with newItem*/
l[l.Count - 1] = newItem.ToString(); // change the last element
//Console.WriteLine(line); // line is the original string don't work
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", l)); // create new string
```

Answer (score 0):

This would probably do the job for you. A word on reading files though, if possible, ie they fit in memory, read the entire file at once, it gives you one disk access (well, depends on file size, but yeah) and you do not have to worry about filehandles.

```
  // Read the stuff from the file, gets an string[]
  var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"file.txt");

  foreach (var line in lines)
  {
      var splitLine = line.Split(' ');
      var score = double.Parse(splitLine.Last(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

      // The math wizard is in town!
      score = score + 3;

      // Put it back
      splitLine[splitLine.Count() - 1] = score.ToString();

      // newLine is the new line, what should we do with it?
      var newLine = string.Join(" ", splitLine);
      // Lets print it cause we are out of ideas!
      Console.WriteLine(newLine);
  }
```

What do you want to do with the end result? Do you want it written back to file?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  string subjectString = "Sean Hollen from Markell 7.22";

  double Substring =double.Parse(subjectString.Substring(subjectString.IndexOf(Regex.Match(subjectString, @"\d+").Value), subjectString.Length - subjectString.IndexOf(Regex.Match(subjectString, @"\d+").Value)).ToString());

  double NewVal = Substring * 10;  // Or any of your operation

  subjectString = subjectString.Replace(Substring.ToString(), NewVal.ToString());
```

**Note:** This will not work if the number appears twice on the same line

Comment: Dangerous, what if the number is twice on the same line? The question specifically states the "last number" :)

Answer (score 0):

You are creating and initializing the list in a loop, hence it contains always only the current line. Do you want to find the highest score of all entertainers or the highest score of each entertainer (in case an entertainer could repeat in the file)?

However, here is an approach that gives you both:

```
var allWithScore = File.ReadAllLines(path)
    .Select(l =>
    {
        var split = l.Split();
        string entertainer = string.Join(" ", split.Skip(1).Take(split.Length - 2));
        double score;
        bool hasScore = double.TryParse(split.Last(), NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out score);
        return new { line = l, split, entertainer, hasScore, score };
    })
    .Where(x => x.hasScore);
// highest score of all:
double highestScore = allWithScore.Max(x => x.score);
// entertainer with highest score 
var entertainerWithHighestScore = allWithScore
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.score)
    .GroupBy(x => x.entertainer)
    .First();
foreach (var x in entertainerWithHighestScore)
    Console.WriteLine("Entertainer:{0} Score:{1}", x.entertainer, x.score);
// all entertainer's highest scores:
var allEntertainersHighestScore = allWithScore
    .GroupBy(x => x.entertainer)
    .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(x => x.score).First());
foreach (var x in allEntertainersHighestScore)
    Console.WriteLine("Entertainer:{0} Score:{1}", x.entertainer, x.score);
```